# Given $x^3$ mod $55$, find its inverse

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

So i am wondering how i can figure out what the functional inverse  of $x^3$ mod $55$ is.

I can only assume it is $x^{1/3}$ mod $55$ but i am not sure if that is the form i should keep it in

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  Do you want the **inverse function** or the reciprocal (the multiplicative inverse)?

Comment: Do mean multiplicative inverse (as you have written) or functional inverse (as in cube root)?

Comment: Not all cubes have an inverse mod $55$.

Comment: In either case, [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem) will be useful.

Comment: I am looking for the inverse function, i guess i mixed things up in my brain here.

Comment: I am curious how Euler's theorem factors into the inverse function here.

Comment: @user2327195 You should make sure that you understand the explanation in the first part of my answer since that is the key idea in many problems like this. I emphasized that since it is not explained at all in the other answer (where, alas, the inverse is pulled out of a hat, like magic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $x^3\equiv y\pmod{55}$, where $y$ is relatively prime to $55$. Then $x^{20}\equiv 1\pmod{55}$, since $x^4\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ and $x^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$.

It follows that $x^{21}\equiv x\pmod{55}$. Note that in fact this congruence holds for **all** $x$. Thus if $y\equiv x^3\pmod{55}$, then
$$x\equiv (x^3)^7\equiv y^7\pmod{55}.$$

Comment: Im curious, could i use the fact that $\phi(55)$ is $40$ giving $x^{40} \equiv 1$ mod $55$ thus $x^81 \equiv x$ mod $55$ hence $y^{27}$ is also an inverse? I am curious as to how you got $x^{20}$, is this a result from Chinese Remainder Thm or something of the sort?

Comment: @user2327195 I explain the key idea in my answer.

Comment: @user2327195 $\,\color{#c00}{x^4\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\,x^{20}\equiv (\color{#c00}{x^4})^5\equiv \color{#c00}{1}^5\equiv 1\pmod{4}\,$ for $x$ coprime to $5$ by little Fermat. Similarly $x^{10}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,x^{20}\equiv 1\pmod{11}\,$ for $x$ coprime to $11$. So for $x$ coprime to $5,11$ we have $x^{20}-1\,$ is divisible by $5$ and $11$ so also by their LCM $= 5\cdot 11,\,$ i.e. $\,x^{20}\equiv 1\pmod{55}$ You could use CRT insteead of the LCM, but that's overkill.

Comment: Ah ok. That makes sense. Though i am still curious if  $y^{27}$ would also be a correct functional inverse as well? Does this mean functions can have many inverses?

Comment: @user2327195 Because $27\equiv 7\pmod{20}$ it follows that $\,y^{27}\equiv y^7\pmod{55}$ for all $y$ coprime to $55$, i.e. they are the *same* functions on the set of such $y$.

Comment: @user2327195 Btw, you can also use [Carmichael's generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) of Euler's theorem to get $\,x^{20}\equiv 1$. This gets a sharper result by combining the powers using LCM (vs. multiplying).

Answer (score 2):

By the remark below $\,x^{\color{#c00}{\large 20}}\equiv 1\pmod{55}\,$ for all for all $x$ coprime to $55$. Thus all exponents on $x$ can be considered to be $\,$ mod $\,\color{#c00}{20}$.

Solving the equation $\ x^{\large 3}\equiv y\pmod{55}\, $ for $\,x\,$ is easy because $\,1/3\,$ exists mod $20$, namely:

Raise both sides to power $\,\color{#0a0}{1/3}\equiv 21/3 \equiv\color{#0a0}7\pmod{\!\color{#c00}{20}}$

Doing that we obtain $\, x \equiv\, (x^{\large 3})^{\large\color{#0a0}{1/3}}\,\equiv\, y^{\large\color{#0a0}7}\pmod{\color{#c00}{20}} $

**Remark** $\,\color{#c00}{x^4\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\,x^{20}\equiv (\color{#c00}{x^4})^5\equiv \color{#c00}{1}^5\equiv 1\pmod{5}\,$ for $x$ coprime to $5$ by little Fermat. Similarly $x^{10}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,x^{20}\equiv 1\pmod{11}\,$ for $x$ coprime to $11$. So for $x$ coprime to $5,11$ we have $x^{20}-1\,$ is divisible by $5$ and $11$ so also by their LCM $= 5\cdot 11,\,$ i.e. $\,x^{20}\equiv 1\pmod{55}\,$  Alternatively, we could use CRT instead of the LCM, but that's a bit overkill.